# Implementing the Shift Property of the Fourier Transform in Mathematica

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I am trying to determine the Fourier tranform of a  time shifted (t-b) Lorentzian function in Mathematica. With the zero centered Lorentzian (b=0), the Integrate function with the conditions that all variables are real, the correct Fourier transform is obtained.

However,  the Fourier Transform of a time shifted Lorenztain is very strange-the output is unexpected, where, $a$ is the area, b is the center and c is the width.

```
y = a/(\[Pi]  c (1 + ((t - b)/c)^2))

Integrate[y*Exp[-I w t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {Element[ t | a | b | c | w, Reals], a > 0, c > 0} ]
```

The output is

```
(1/(2 \[Pi]))a (I Cos[(b + I c) Abs[
       w]] CosIntegral[-((b + I c) Abs[w])] - 
   I Cos[(b + I c) Abs[w]] CosIntegral[(b + I c) Abs[
       w]] + \[Pi] Cos[(b - I c) Abs[w]] Sign[
     w] - \[Pi] Cos[(b + I c) Abs[w]] Sign[w] - 
   I \[Pi] Sin[(b - I c) Abs[w]] - 
   CosIntegral[-((b - I c) Abs[w])] (I Cos[(b - I c) Abs[w]] + 
      Sign[w] Sin[(b - I c) Abs[w]]) + 
   CosIntegral[(b - I c) Abs[w]] (I Cos[(b - I c) Abs[w]] + 
      Sign[w] Sin[(b - I c) Abs[w]]) + I \[Pi] Sin[(b + I c) Abs[w]] +
    CosIntegral[-((b + I c) Abs[w])] Sign[w] Sin[(b + I c) Abs[w]] - 
   CosIntegral[(b + I c) Abs[w]] Sign[w] Sin[(b + I c) Abs[w]])
```

What is the best way to correctly calculate time shifted Fourier transforms in Mathematica? I was expecting a complex exponential multiplier with the original FT of the zero centered Lorentzian.

**EDITS**
The correct answer, as per the shift property, should be the exponential factor multiplied by the FT of the zero centered Lorentzian, i.e., Exp[-I w b]*Exp[-Abs[w] c]*a or

```
a*Exp[-I b w - c Abs[w]]
```

This is  similar to answer shown in the comments if we impose w>0. However, this condition is not required for a zero centered Lorentzian and the absolute sign comes *automatically* if we set b=0. What is causing this problem with the time shifted Lorentzian? Thanks.

Comment: `Exp[-I w t]`,right?

Comment: (I corrected OP's typo, since evaluating the correct version of the code leads to OP's output, so it must have been a transcription error.)

Comment: Note that with `sol = Integrate[...]`, `FullSimplify[sol, {Element[t | a | b | c | w, Reals], a > 0, c > 0}]` gives `Piecewise[{{a*E^((-I)*b*w - c*w), w > 0}, {0, w < 0}}, Indeterminate]`. (adding `w > 0` to the list of assumptions in the original integral returns just `a E^-((I b + c) w)`) is this what you expected?

Comment: Thank you. The FT of a zero centered Lorentzian does not require that w>0. The absolute sign comes in automatically. Thanks for suggesting FullSimplify, this gives a hint where the integral is valid.